# Android: NullPointerException when communicating between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

Android newbie here. My app crashes when trying to send text from one fragment to another. It says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.hang.camera.Camera.sendResults(Camera.java:57)
            at com.example.hang.camera.PageOneFragment.sendMethod(PageOneFragment.java:320)
            at com.example.hang.camera.PageOneFragment$1.onClick(PageOneFragment.java:104)
```

Here is my code:

// Activity that implements the interface from fragment A

Camera.java:

```
public class Camera extends ActionBarActivity implements PageOneFragment.OnComputeResultListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();

    mViewPager = (CustomViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, mTabHost, mViewPager);

    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("one").setIndicator("One"), PageOneFragment.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("two").setIndicator("Two"), PageTwoFragment.class, null);

    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }

    mViewPager.setPagingEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void sendResults(String text){
    PageTwoFragment fragmentTwo =     (PageTwoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.second_fragment);
    fragmentTwo.updateText(text);
}
```

// fragment A:

PageOneFragment.java

```
OnComputeResultListener mCallback;
public interface OnComputeResultListener{
    public void sendResults(String text);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try{
        mCallback = (OnComputeResultListener) activity;
    } catch(ClassCastException e){
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnComputeResultListener");
    }
}

public void sendMethod(){
    mCallback.sendResults("the results");
}

// in onCreateView, I have this onclicklistener, and I call "sendMethod" here 
lengthButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){

                    double length ;
                    line_x = imageview.x_getter();
                    line_y = imageview.y_getter();

                    length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((line_x[0]-line_x[1]),2) + Math.pow((line_y[0]-line_y[1]),2));

                    line_length.setText("Length of the line is: " + String.format("%.2f",length) + "dp");

                    sendMethod();

                }
            }
    );
```

// fragment B
PageTwoFragment.java

```
private TextView resultText = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pagetwo_fragment, container, false);

    resultText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.resultText);

    return view;
}

public void updateText(String text){
    resultText.setText(text);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. In my camera.java where I implemented "sendResults" method of the interface, I changed the parameter of "findFragmentById" to the id of the viewPager instead of the id of the fragment's xml file.

However, from Android developer doc, for findFragmentById, it does say:

```
Finds a fragment that was identified by the given id either when inflated from XML or as the container ID when added in a transaction.
```

So, I don't know why the xml id didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can save your Fragment as an object in your Activity class.
In the activity class before doing the fragment transaction, do the following:

```
 PageTwoFragment fragmentTwo = new  PageTwoFragment();
 // do the transaction:
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();          
ft.replace(R.id.container, fragmentTwo);
ft.commit();
```

then later in code, just call

```
fragmentTwo.updateText(...);
```